# (Why) should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I think [How to cause a missed shapeshift roll for Dungeon World](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22814/23970) should be closed: it fits all the hallmarks for the things that make list/idea-generation questions bad. There are a number of good, non-overlapping answers with no real way to tell which is "better" than another for voting purposes.

But...

- It's not a **duplicate**
- It's possibly **off-topic** for a **custom reason** of... I'm-not-sure-what?
- It's not **unclear**
- It's possibly **too broad** because "there are too many possible answers," but the fact that it's only generated three answers makes that seem a little petty
- It doesn't seem **Primarily opinion-based**, as the answers speak from excellent experience

I believe this question is an obvious candidate for closure. But *why*?

Comment: Unrelated: ***I, too, wish emphasis worked in question titles!***

Comment: @HeyICanChan Emphasis like italics etc?  Huh, I had not even tried to use that before.

Comment: @HeyICanChan MathJax is rendered in titles, though, so if you're `\$\text{\emph{dying}}\$` to shoehorn it in there....

Comment: But unfortunately changes the font face/weight.

Answer (score 2):

It need not be closed.

In the text of the question we get a "how do I do this?" which fits the general theme of problem solving.

> but how can you make shapeshifting turn out bad?

While there is a trace of "idea generation" and the title looks that way, I edited the title to get rid of "idea" and the question is still OK.  The best answer, be it from pure rule citation or experience (you note that there is an answer with each feature) should receive support.

Comment: I agree, there's some "tell me some great ideas for this" questions which can actually be handled from expertise, and just need rephrasing to "tell me how I handle this situation". That turns it from idea generation, to one that invites people to explain the basic principles of the situation that help them generate _their own_ ideas (and ideas may be given as examples).

Answer (score 2):

I think this question lives in a nebulous area between an infinite list question and a rules question. The rules question aspect is mostly a quirk of the Dungeon World system. The actual question asked is:

> how can you make shapeshifting turn out bad?

In context of the system, it means the player rolled a 6-. The only possible answer within the rules is "The GM picks one of the 12 GM moves to use in response". It only gets infinite-list-y if people start providing tons of different ideas about how to implement one of those 12 moves.

The answers aren't exactly pouring in, and the currently Accepted answer is one that starts with a framework of the rules. As such, I think it's a case of a potentially too broad question that has successfully been reined in with a few good answers.

Answer (score 0):

If it's closeable it would be the **too broad** reason because "it's an idea-generation / infinite list question." Even if it hasn't been expanding steadily, unending ideas is what the question is asking for — the limited number of answers is just because of the smaller audience for DW questions.

If it gets closed, too broad would definitely be why.

Alternatively, the answers aren't terribly list-y so far; if you squint, they could be answering a related, "How do I choose miss consequences for the Shapeshift move?" question instead. The question could be modified to no longer be asking for ideas in such a way that the answers are still properly answering the new question — the ideas provided in the answers then become working examples of their methods instead of just an idea list.

On the other hand, maybe on closer inspection that wouldn't actually work perfectly, or the answers wouldn't still fit quite right or they'd need modifying to fit the new question. But its a slightly out-of-box avenue to explore when something in a question makes us hesitate to vote it closed.